# Selecting visio shape and running add-in for the selected shape

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, add-in, visio

I have created a visio add-in using vb.net. The add-in, when clicked, shows a form which is used to insert shape data rows for a selected shape.

Process:

Drop shape on page >> Select the shape (if not selected) >> Click the add-in button >> Windows form shows up

This works perfectly when I drop the first shape. But when I drop another shape from the same master and click the add-in button, the form does not show up.

I have this code for it:

```
Dim xPS as Visio.Shape
xPS = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem

    If xPS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & vbCrLf & "No 'AA' shape selected. Please select an 'AA' shape and rerun the command")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'If a shape other than 'AA' is selected, a message box is displayed with error description.
        If Left(xPS.Name, 2) <> "AA" Then
            MsgBox("ERROR: " & vbCrLf & "Incorrect shape selected." & vbCrLf & "Please select 'AA' shape and rerun the command.")
            Exit Sub
        Else
             xCT.Show()          'Shows the user form
        End If
   End If
```

I have a doubt that I am not using the correct syntax for selected shape.

`xPS = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem`

Can someone please tell me why the form does not show up for second shape, but it does for the first one?

Thanks for the help.

Miki

Comment: To get the definitive answer you need to debug the code and see what happens under the hood. I'd suggest from breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring each property and method call on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to see what each property or method call returns.

Comment: Debugging the code run the add-in properly until I select the shape which was dropped first on the drawing. However, when there are more than one shape from the same master, then I will not show the form for the second shape. I am going to try what you suggested to see what exactly is happening.
I also tried to check with macro recorder, however, it did not yield anything fruitful.

Comment: You should probably be checking the master name rather than the shape's name.  So try xPS.Master.NameU instead.  Also, I assume you're using a similar method to retrieve the selected shape somewhere in your form's code so I would check that is working correctly too.